# Undefined token error when shader file saved in unicode

Tags: opengl, glsl

Why do i get undefined token error when the shader text file is saved in unicode , when i save it back in ansi the error goes away.

```
#version 330 core
layout( location = 0 ) in vec2 aPos;
layout( location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;
void main()
{
   gl_Position = vec4(aPos , 0.0 , 1.0);
};
```

Comment: GLSL source code should not contain non-Latin characters, or there might be compiler errors - which is expected, so what it the question?
What does "saved in UNICODE" means? GLSL code is passed to OpenGL as char*, so that there should be clarification how your code snippet actually arrives in OpenGL.
In case if you use text editor for GLSL code - do not save UTF-8 with BOM and do not save in UTF-16 or similar, or perform necessary processing while reading these text files in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [OpenGL spec](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Compilation) takes a `char*` as the array to compile the data. `char`'s are usually a byte so they can take at most 256 values, which is ASCII.

If you give it a string that tries to encode a larger character representation (e.g UTF-16) it will interpret the data as if it was a `char*` which means the compiler is now reading the byte prefix in the larger representation as if it was its own, unique value.

This is of course undefined behaviour and likely to not work.